# How to add 301 redirection ( from http to https ) in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

How to add 301 redirection ( from http to https ) in Next.js?

For example - from this "http://stackoverflow.com/" to this "https://stackoverflow.com/" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from _app.js, by doing this:

```
res.writeHead(301, { Location: `https://${req?.headers.host}/${asPath}` })
```

If you have forvarded-proto header then you can also check:

```
req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'http'
```

Otherwise you must determine if you are at `http` or `https` by yourself, as an example you can try parsing the url:

```
const url = new URL('http://example.com')
console.log(url.protocol) // output: "http:"
```

Comment: how can I know if I use HTTP or https ?
i always see undefined in req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] and req.connection.encrypted